# How are live tiles made in Windows 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, live-tile

I've searched the samples, the developer site, the getting started and the enhancing *bla bla bla* pages.

Even using some search queries on Google, I can't seem any information on live tiles in Windows 8.

How do I create a live tile in Windows 8? What languages can be used for that? C#? XAML?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211386

You can use either C# or VB + XAML or HTML/JS or C++.

That was the big announcement at the BUILD conference and the whole point of WinRT (God I hope they actually are serious about pushing WinRT for more than a year).

Otherwise it would be back to the Silverlight/.Net uprising that we saw after the first preview. . .

**edit**

You'll first need to learn the terminology of the MetroUI.  You can also find more info under Windows Phone 7.

The Live Tiles can send tile notifications.  That's how the socialite tile does the facebook feed.  The OS will *cycle* through tile notifications that you've declared.  This is all in the basic Tile sample and the advanced Tile sample.

[Here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-Developer-Preview-6b53adbb) is a link to all the samples from the BUILD event.

Start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/) for a step by step walkthrough of the platform. I would start there if the reference documentation is confusing.

Comment: Now, how do I get the tile to update? The documentation is confusing, there doesn't seem to be an example or tutorial that explicitly shows how to update a tile... :(

Comment: You are looking for tile notifications.

Comment: +1 I thought a notification was supposed to interrupt the user to notify him somethnig, how's that called?

Comment: @Tom wijsman: To grab the user's attention, you should use a Toast notification.  Toasts are those small windows that slide out on the lower right.

Answer (score 41):

Finally figured it out, these live tiles are using tile notifications *as noted by others*.

Here is the minimal code necessary for updating an existing default tile with a template:

1. You have to load in a [template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.tiletemplatetype%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and adjust it, or produce your own XML code. See the [tile schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212859%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)...

   ```
   var tileXml = Notifications.TileUpdateManager.getTemplateContent(template);
   ```
2. You need to create a notification, which apparently is an update to a tile.

   ```
   var notification = new Notifications.TileNotification(tileXml);
   ```
3. You need to create an updater, which will provide you with methods to notify through your tile.

   ```
   var upd = Notifications.TileUpdateManager.createTileUpdaterForApplication();
   ```
4. If you have all this, you can send an update to the client.

   ```
   upd.update(notification);
   ```

Answer (score 7):

The documents for notifications have been updated since the Consumer Preview release - a good starting point is the ['choosing a notification delivery method'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779721.aspx) document.

It has all of the relevant pointers to push, polling, scheduled and local notifications.

Answer (score 3):

The available Metro documentation is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/

It's pretty patchy at the moment but there are samples, such as:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Advanced-Tiles-Sample-1995ac42

Not all the samples are available in multiple languages, and that tile example is JS only, but based on what I've read elsewhere, it seems everything can be done with .NET languages, native (C++) or JS using the same APIs.

Comment: I've found [Creating and using tiles, toast, and Windows push notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465360%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), it however doesn't display how to update tiles and I can't seem to find a sample that updates a tile with live information (and perhaps an animation) and don't know where I would need to look in the code. The [TileUpdateManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.tileupdatemanager%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) lists no sample code for this, so I'm clueless... :(

Answer (score 1):

[App tiles and badges sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-tiles-and-badges-sample-5fc49148) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[NotificationExtension library](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Toast-notifications-sample-52eeba29) (part of MSDN sample in toast notification, application tile notification ) is very easy to use.

For tile/toast notification updates following approaches can be used

1. Directly from the application
2. From the background tasks
3. From the WNS (push notification service)

Thorough samples are available in [msdn code samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-Modern-Style-App-Samples)