# How to register for Win8 periodic tile notifications?

Tags: notifications, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I am working on a Win8-UI-App (previously called Metro...) and trying to implement Periodic ([Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779721.aspx) for different methods) Tile Updates (Live Tiles) for the first time.

I found a couple of very good resources on the internet and was able to do it. Unfortunately the question of where I should register for the notifications remained unsolved:

Do I have to register for Notifications ***every time*** the app starts (e.g. in the App.xaml.cs OnLaunched() Method)? - Or is there an other, more professional way to do so? (I could imagine to save if I already registered for the service or is there a variable I can access to see whether notifications are registered?)

thank you!

PS: For everyone who is also new to this see this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442760/how-are-live-tiles-made-in-windows-8), this [example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Push-and-periodic-de225603), the [tile template types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.tiletemplatetype) and the [Dev Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150587.aspx) for quick starting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Periodic updates will continue until they are [explicitly stopped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx) or your app is uninstalled.  Technically, you only have to do that once.  But, the [Guidelines and checklist for periodic updates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx) states

> Call the StartPeriodicUpdate or StartPeriodicUpdateBatch method each
>   time your app is launched or brought into focus. This ensures that the
>   tile content will be updated each time the user launches or switches
>   to the app.

According to that, [App launch and App resume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx) are good candidates for a call to [StartPeriodicUpdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.notifications.tileupdater.aspx).