# HttpClient.GetAsync fails in background task with lock screen access and both TimeTrigger or MaintenanceTrigger

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Client.GetAsync appears to fail for me when running in a background task in my Windows 8 Metro app.

I tried using both a TimeTrigger and a MaintenanceTrigger. It appears that there is no exception. When debugging it, it just exits at that line (if I keep pressing step over), even though there is way more to execute as well as a try-catch around it.

This leads me to believe that Windows is cancelling my task. So I listened to the cancelled event with no luck.

I have declared Internet access as a capability, and the task has been properly registered. Furthermore, my app has full lock screen access.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code I use to register the background task currently.

```
if (await ObtainLockScreenAccess())
{
    const string name = "Task";

    var updaterTasks = BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks.Where(t => t.Value.Name == name);
    if (!updaterTasks.Any())
    {

        var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
        builder.Name = name;
        builder.TaskEntryPoint = "Stackstabilizer.BackgroundTasks.UpdateBackgroundTask";

        var trigger = new MaintenanceTrigger(15, false);
        var condition = new SystemCondition(SystemConditionType.InternetAvailable);

        builder.AddCondition(condition);
        builder.SetTrigger(trigger);

        var task = builder.Register();

        Debug.WriteLine("Task has been registered");

    }
}
```

**Edit** Here's the background task signature:

```
namespace Stackstabilizer.BackgroundTasks
{
    // You must use a sealed class, and make sure the output is a WINMD. 
    public sealed class UpdateBackgroundTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {

            var deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

            try { ... } finally { deferral.Complete(); }

        }
     }

}
```

And here's some details on my declarations.

[image]

Comment: Can you share your background task code as well?

Comment: The background task is long. However the point is that it doesn't even reach the first line. I'll provide the signature instead.

Comment: Are you waiting on the async calls?  As soon as deferral.Complete() is called, the background task is assumed to be finished.  If it is called before the async methods finish, some code in the background task entry point may not execute.  Based on your other posts, I assume you are using this background task to update your tile based on web content.  Have you considered using the periodic tile update APIs (TileUpdater.StartPeriodicUpdate) instead?  If they fit your needs, you wouldn't need to write a background task.

Comment: I update both tiles and do toast notifications. Can TileUpdater do that for me? Also, can the TileUpdater update my tiles even after I close the app again, at given intervals - and can it access the Internet?

Comment: Periodic tile updates allow Windows to automatically hit a web URL on behalf of an application on a fixed interval, even when the app is not running.  Periodic tile updates cannot be used for toast notifications.  If an app is not running, toast notifications can only be raised via push or scheduled notifications.  I recommend you read this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779721.aspx

Comment: The StartPeriodicUpdate function takes in a URI for the tile content. I don't have such a URI. The tiles are not generated from the web, but my own application. What options do I have in this scenario?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17332/discussion-between-nathan-kuchta-msft-and-mathias-lykkegaard-lorenzen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem to you before, and the way I solved it was to have another deferral in the async task. I think the idea is that, whenever you have an async task, you need a deferral. (I'm not sure if it's best practice, but hey, it works)

Code:

```
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        updateAllTiles(taskInstance);
    }


    public async void updateAllTiles(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        // Need to use a deferral to run async tasks in the background task
        BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

        dosomething(taskInstance);

        deferral.Complete();
    }

    private async void dosomething(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage resp = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(url));

        updateTile(resp);

        deferral.Complete();
    }
```